# 12.10 - Touchegg: can't add repository

Tags: 12.10, add-apt-repository, touchegg

I would like to add some multi-touch gestures, like those on a Mac device.
Therefore I want to install Touchegg but I get this error

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:utouch-team/daily
Cannot access PPA (https://launchpad.net/api/1.0/~utouch-team/+archive/daily)
       to get PPA information, please check your internet connection.
```

Comment: Well, the error is obvious in its suggestion: is your internet connection working? I mean, the [URL](https://launchpad.net/api/1.0/~utouch-team/+archive/daily) works for me. In case you're using a proxy, mention this in your question.

Comment: My Internet works fine. And I'm not connected to the internet via a proxy server. Right now I'm at a friends house and the problems still occurs.